# Error in building ndk library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

I have an android project with a native part. Now I am trying to make eclipse compile all things but during the native compilation it gives me this error:

```
sh ndk-build all 
ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: C:/cygwin/bin/make

To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

Now I can compile it from Cygwin and it works. It also works from eclipse in my other computer with exactly the same paths.

I found that if I launch `ndk-build` from cygwin it is all right but if I launch "sh ndk-build" it gives me the error of eclipse.

I think this is the problem, but I do not know why prepending the command with `sh` it does not work (also prepending it with bash gives me the error ).

Someone can help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which NDK version are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem solved,
The ndk path was not properly setted in eclipse preferences.
(in eclipse Window->preferences->Android->NDK->NDK_Location)