# build_native.sh running error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm currently trying to follow one of Lynda.com's tutorials, and I'm getting this error while I'm running 'build_native.sh' file on cygwin.

```
 /cygdrive/c/Users/Gideon/Documents/My-Android-Project/cocos2d-x/moleitx/proj.android
$ ./build_native.sh
Using prebuilt externals
ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: C:/mingw/bin/make
```

To solve the issue, follow these steps:

```
1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

I tried to search to solve this problem I could not find it.
Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Are you still looking for this? I'm currently working on similar problems.

I think your NDK path might not be set up correctly.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674640/error-in-building-ndk-library?rq=1).

This only worked for me after reinstalling NDK since I didn't have the option to set the NDK path; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723712/eclipse-juno-adt-plugin-ndk-path-removed)